# httpClient.get() method not fetching data

Tags: angular, get, httpclient

I am trying to get data using `httpClient.get()` method from Codeignitor API. But it is not working.

```
loginUser(event){
   console.log(event);
   console.log('this');
   this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/Ideabucket/idea- 
   bucket/api/index.php/Welcome/get_data').subscribe(
      (data:any[])=>{
      console.log(data.length);
   )
}
```

But when I call the API in browser, the data is displayed. Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the whole code? and what do you see inside console.log(data);

Comment: I am getting this error in console. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CORS issue, solution 1:

To fix it add this at the top:

```
<?php  
  'header(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)';
  'header(Content-Type: application/json)'
?>
```

Comment: Better set it to `http://localhost:4200` instead of `*` and similarly to the domain name when it goes live.

Comment: This one worked. Have to add these code in constructor